# How to make a Singleton Database class to write data into Sqllite db?

Tags: android

Even though I create a static class to hold the database helper instance, I'm confused as to where do I instantiate the class. And how do I ensure that only one instance of the class is available?

What I meant to say is, I'm confused in which activity and how should I be instatiating the class for it to remain one instance?

Not sure why the downvotes.

Initially, I had a

```
public class DbStaticClass {

    public static LinkDataHandler sqlDataHandler = null;
}
```

Which I intialized at Splashscreen as that's the entrant activity. But it always caused multiple instances of Sqllite db. Hence, I'm confused where do I do it?

Comment: Hard to tell without more code -- so far, we don't see you instantiating it once, much less multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

> But it always caused multiple instances of Sqllite db.

You can't have a Singleton class in Android, because the life cycle of Android Activity class (and even the Process) is not tied to the life cycle of the Application, Android can instantiate and destroy your Activity at any time. Instead of Singleton, you want write a Borg instead; instead of relying on there being exactly one instance of the class, multiple Borg instances should behave with a hive mind.

Comment: Unfortunately had never heard of Borg before this.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that only one instance of the class is available?

It seems you are defining singleton in a wrong way. Singleton itself ensures that only one instance of the class is available. The right way to do is:

```
public class SQLiteBaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SQLiteBaseClass mInstance;

    private SQLiteBaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static SQLiteBaseClass getInstance(Context c) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new SQLiteBaseClass(c);
        }
            return mInstance;
    }
 }
```

Now, wherever you need to do database operations simply call `SqliteBaseClass.getnstance()`

For detailed desription you can read my blog entry [here](http://www.gauravarora.me/?p=137)